# My Drop down menus using Bootstrap 3 is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code for the navbar. On its own, it works fine. There are no errors. I copied it from getbootstrap.com/components but as soon as the next line of codes are added it stops working.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default header-nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.tradenepal.com.np" target="_blank">Trade Nepal</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="profile.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

If I don't put the following codes, the menu works perfectly fine, but as soon as I add div, it just stops working.

```
<div class="container" style="padding:10px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading">Pages Section</div>
        <ol class="list-group">                             
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="#" id="1" class="delete_button" />
                  <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
                  </span>
                 </a>
                 <a href="#" />Some Text</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vk8kuu0d/)**! There are some html syntax errors in your page! check the anchor tag in panel! You are closing it with `<a... />` and then with `</a>` again!! I don't think that might be the reason.. but still its better to be specific regarding the problem!!

Comment: where you add the second div ? it will be nice if you edit it and snippet.

Comment: I don't think <a... /> and </a> is same. I am just using the norm here.

The second div is the class "container". As soon as I add it, the drop down doesn't work. Anyways, I coded it around the container and now is working fine.